# How to convert this MySQL query to Eloquent?

Tags: mysql, laravel, eloquent

I am trying to convert a raw SQL query into eloquent and I am struggling with the join part as it gets quite complex.

I have got as far as the joins but I am looking at the documentation and struggling to work out how to convert the rest.

Here is the raw query

```
SELECT
SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'lead',
SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'in_review',
SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'pre_app_sent',
SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'pre_app_back',
SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'pre_app_ok',
SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'awaiting_kyc',
SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'kyc_complete',
SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'awaiting_full_app_data',
SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'full_app_sent',
SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'merchant_live'
FROM leads l
JOIN (SELECT
        ae.id,
        ae.model_id,
        ae.fields,
        TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ae.fields,';', 1), ':', -1)) AS field_1,
        TRIM(BOTH '"' FROM SUBSTRING_INDEX(SUBSTRING_INDEX(ae.fields,';', 2), ':', -1)) AS field_2,
        ae.created_at
        FROM action_events ae) t2
ON l.id = t2.model_id
WHERE t2.created_at >= '2019-01-01 00:00:00'
AND t2.created_at <= '2019-01-31 23:59:59'
```

And here is as far as I got with converting it to eloquent

```
$query->select(
DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "lead"'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 2 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "in_review"'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 3 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "pre_app_sent"'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 4 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "pre_app_back"'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 5 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "pre_app_ok"'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "awaiting_kyc"'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "kyc_complete"'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 8 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "awaiting_full_app_data"'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 9 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "full_app_sent"'),
                    DB::raw('SUM(CASE WHEN t2.field_2 = 10 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS "merchant_live"'));
```

Comment: Eloquent is a pretty wrapper around QueryBuilder, which is also a pretty wrapper of PDO statements. You won't be able to accomplish this in eloquent without being an overkill. You can write it as a query builder

Comment: How would I achieve this? The $query variable is a QueryBuilder instance as I am overriding the default index query on a laravel nova resource